# How do I verify specific Cell Value in an Excel Sheet through Pandas Data Frame in Python3.7

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I have an Excel Sheet having some values, one such cell has Yes/No written in it. Since I have linked the entire file in Python and made a Data Frame of it, how do I verify specific cell values so that only the rows with No value can be printed?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r'/Volumes/SSD/Project/Raw_Data/Light.xlsx')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data , columns = ['Person in Room'] ) //Help Needed
```

Comment: You just want to print all rows with NaN values from Light.xlsx right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do these following steps:**

```
# Takes in Light.xlsx as dataframe
datacheck = pd.read_excel(r'/Volumes/SSD/Project/Raw_Data/Light.xlsx')

# Prints all rows with NaN values
datacheck[datacheck.isna().any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: How to check a certain value? Eg. one such row has names written in it and I want to print column in which the value is "Fan"